# Move to user location marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code that set multiple markers, and I'm new to Google Maps API, and trying to learn how to set the map to automatically show current user's location marker. The tutorial I get it is set the map centre upon receiving all markers. Here is my code:-

```
<script>
var startPos, positionPromise = $.Deferred();

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    startPos = position;
    $('#pok_lat').val(startPos.coords.latitude); 
    $('#pok_long').val(startPos.coords.longitude);

    positionPromise.resolve();

}, function(error) {
    alert('Error occurred. Error code: ' + error.code + '');
    // error.code can be:
    //   0: unknown error
    //   1: permission denied
    //   2: position unavailable (error response from locaton provider)
    //   3: timed out

    positionPromise.reject();

});

$(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SOMEAPIKEY&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

window["initialize"] = function() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    // Multiple Markers LatLong
    $.when(positionPromise).then(function(){
            var lats = document.getElementById("pokemon_lat").value;
            var longi = document.getElementById("pokemon_long").value;
            console.log('Lat:'+lats+' Long:'+longi);

    var markers = [
        ['You are here!', lats,longi],
        <?php
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($pok_info); $x++) {
            if ($x < count($pok_info)) {
                $addcomma = ",";
            }
            else {
                $addcomma = "";
            }
            $pok_array[] = "['".$pok_info[$x]['name']."', ".$pok_info[$x]['lat'].",".$pok_info[$x]['long']."]".$addcomma;

        }

            $remove_comma = count($pok_array);  
            $remove_comma = $remove_comma - 1;
            $pok_array[$remove_comma] = rtrim($pok_array[$remove_comma],',');
                foreach ($pok_array as $value) {
                echo $value;
            }
        ?>
    ];

    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['You are here!'],
        <?php
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($pok_info); $x++) {
            if ($x < count($pok_info)) {
                $addcomma = ",";
            }
            else {
                $addcomma = "";
            }
            $pok_array_info[] = "['<div class=\"info_content\"><h3>".$pok_info[$x]['name']."</h3><br><img width=\"100\" height=\"100\" src=\"".$pok_info[$x]['pic']."\"><p>".$pok_info[$x]['description']."</p>']".$addcomma;

        }

            $remove_comma = count($pok_array_info); 
            $remove_comma = $remove_comma - 1;
            $pokemon_array_info[$remove_comma] = rtrim($pok_array_info[$remove_comma],',');
                foreach ($pok_array_info as $value) {
                echo $value;
            }
        ?>
    ];

    // Pok Icons

     var pokeImage = [ 
        ['images/pokeball.png'],
        <?php

            $img_icons = array();

            for ($x = 0; $x < count($pok_info); $x++) {
                $img_icon = $pok_info[$x]['pic'];
                $img_icon = explode(".",$img_icon);
                $img_icons[] = $img_icon[0]."_small.png";
                $addcomma = ",";

            $pok_array_info_pic[] = "['".$img_icons[$x]."']".$addcomma;

        }


            $remove_comma = count($pok_array_info_pic); 
            $remove_comma = $remove_comma - 1;
            $pok_array_info[$remove_comma] = rtrim($pok_array_info_pic[$remove_comma],',');
                foreach ($pok_array_info_pic as $value) {
                echo $value;
            }

            ?>
     ];

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0],
            icon: pokeImage[i][0]   
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
       //map.fitBounds(bounds);
       //console.log('Lat:'+lats)+' Long:'+parseInt(longi));
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(14);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

    }, function(){
            console.log("Could not get latitude and longitude )-:");
        });

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to read user current latitude longitude without his permission so either you should use Geo Location or let user manually enter his/her location manually.

```
<html>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</html>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
         }


    drawMap(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude)
    });
    function drawMap(element, latitude, longitude)
    {
        latitude = latitude || 23.83;
        longitude = longitude || 84.31;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var mapOptions = {zoom: 7, center:latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, mapTypeControl: false};
        map = new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions);
    }
    </script>
```

or second possibility:-

```
<html>
<input type="text" id="latitude">
<input type="text" id="longitude">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </html>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
     var latitude = document.getElementById("latitude");
     var latitude = document.getElementById("longitude");
   drawMap(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),latitude,longitude)
        });
        function drawMap(element, latitude, longitude)
        {
            latitude = latitude || 23.83;
            longitude = longitude || 84.31;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            var mapOptions = {zoom: 7, center:latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, mapTypeControl: false};
            map = new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions);
        }
        </script>
```

But it is browser dependent.

```
Currently the W3C Geolocation API is supported by the following desktop browsers:

Firefox 3.5+
Chrome 5.0+
Safari 5.0+
Opera 10.60+
Internet Explorer 9.0+
There is also support for the W3C Geolocation API on mobile devices:

Android 2.0+
iPhone 3.0+
Opera Mobile 10.1+
Symbian (S60 3rd & 5th generation)
Blackberry OS 6
Maemo
```

In Browsers If:-
In the "Privacy" section location section off then we can not trace the location Using This Geocode so User should keep hi location On in Browser.

You just write this in your code it will center to the map

```
  var latitude = document.getElementById('pok_lat');
    var longitude = document.getElementById('pok_long'); 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    window["initialize"] = function() {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
            center:latlng,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };
```

**As of Chrome 5.0, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts such as HTTPS. If your site is hosted on an non-secure origin (such as HTTP) the requests to get the users location will no longer function.**

Comment: I managed to get the user location, just that how can I just center the map of the user's location? There will be alot of other markers in the map, but I just want to center the user's location marker. Do you understand what I meant?

Comment: Okij so before ploting the Map you have to Iterate all the marker present in Your database where you can check the and pass that latitude longitude to drawmap mthod

Comment: var mapOptions = {zoom: 7, center:latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, mapTypeControl: false}; I have give the option center:latlng which will center to the give latitude longitude in Map

Comment: I have changed the code according to You what you want you can thrugh

Comment: Upon dragging the map, `common.js:154 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`, this error came out

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_first look at this linkand replace the latitude an longitude of ur wish it will render to that latitude longitude bro. I have tried therealso

Comment: @MuthaFury bro you are doing some complexity using PHP other what i have tried everything is working just smoothly. you need to debug the code and find out line no where problem is coming

Comment: Thanks mate, will look into it.